# Spring Boot Kafka: How to prevent to consume the same messages if I restart the consumer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

- I start the kafka and I produce 1000 messages in topic `user`
- I create a Spring Boot Consumer that listens on this topic and saves the messages in the database

What if I close the consumer application and then start it again? How to prevent to save the same messages in the database?

What if the consumer processes the 1000 messages, I stop the consumer, produce 1000 more messages and start the consumer?

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers:
        - localhost:9092
      group-id: "myGroup"
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  datasource:
    username: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase
    password: admin
```

Comment: There's a Kafka Connect sink to Postgres over jdbc, which doesn't require any code, by the way. Had you tried that?

Comment: Nope, at the moment I am just learning kafka.

Comment: That's okay. Kafka Connect is part of Kafka. You can learn that too

Answer (score 0):

> The “auto-offset-reset” property accepts the following values:
>
> - earliest: This value automatically resets the offset to the earliest    offset
> - latest: This value automatically resets the offset to the    latest offset
> - none: This value throws an exception to the consumer if    no previous offset is found for the consumer’s group.

As mentioned, earliest might be the safest offset setting to use if your consumer starts after a few days or so and there are some messages not consumed. This will make sure that no messages are dropped.
You can also keep a track of the message ids from queue and check whether they were already processed or not.

If all this is not part of your worries then you can also use 'latest' to just start fetching from the latest offset.

Edit: Source
https://www.baeldung.com/java-kafka-consumer-api-read

Answer (score 0):

> What if I close the consumer application and then start it again?

Depends on how you commit and other things. If you consume a record, auto-commit the offset to Kafka, and the environment goes down before you've processed it, you just lost a record.

If you're not making sure that there are no duplicates with e.g. idempotent producer and all the other necessary things, you could get duplicates from various places, starting with producer retries.

If you're saving something to a transactional storage (like database), you can store the Kafka offsets in the database in the same transaction as the data, this will make the database the source of truth for Kafka offsets, and you can `seek()` to the correct position on startup to make sure there are no dropped records (it won't help against records duplicated somewhere before the consumer though).

> What if the consumer processes the 1000 messages, I stop the consumer, produce 1000 more messages and start the consumer?

You should know that Kafka won't drop messages even if there's no consumer to read them. I suggest reading up on Kafka internal workings, as it's pretty complicated and `spring-kafka` makes it look easier than it is.

Comment: Except Kafka will drop messages, regardless of there being a consumer, after a week, by default

Comment: Kafka will drop messages if retention time or space is exceeded, yes. But you can still configure infinite retention if you know what you're doing (and need it for some reason, such as using Kafka as a data backbone in the system).

Answer (score 0):

you should set: `auto-offset-reset:latest`

in this way consumer start to consumes from last offset that have been read.